# how to read multiple mysql(H2) table and write to csv file in spring boot batch?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, export-to-csv

I have three tables in mysql database. And I need to read those file and write in CSV file. in these case. How to write multiple table of same database to in CSV file ?

Tabale A

```
ID|    Name
1 |    jhon
2 |    riya
null|    null
```

---

table B:

---

```
Married|    Age    |    Phone
Y      |    35     |    No
N      |    25     |    Yes
Y      |    45     |    No
```

---

Table C

```
ID|    Name  |   Married    |    Age    |     Phone
1 |    Ted   |   Y          |    35     |     No
2 |    Marry |   N          |    25     |     Yes
null|  null  |   Y          |    45     |     No
```

Comment: Is this a one-off?  If so get yourself a client like mysqldump or HeidiSQL and use it to write the CSVs. Otherwise, you can surely find a Spring-compatible class to write CSVs to files. And, keep in mind that "CSV" means comma-separated values. It's not hard to write CSVs yourself.  (Reading? Harder. Because there are all kinds of hairy edge cases.)

Comment: I need to use spring boot batch to schedule batch job. I could not figure out a Spring-compatible class. I found only single table reading example only.

Comment: In your example, can you show the expected CSV file?